# Switch activity from a AlertDialog button

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I'm working on a map based application . Let's say , I have three classes : MapsActivity , MyItemizedOverlay & GetDirectionActivity . In MyItemizedOverlay , I want to switch to GetDirectionActivity after the positive dialog button is clicked . ActiveDialog is placed under onTap method , so that I can get the GeoPoint. For this , what I've done : 
In ItemizedOverlay class :

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int lat = p.getLatitudeE6();
    int lot = p.getLongitudeE6();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
    dialog.setMessage("Confirm this as end point ?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GetDestination.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
    dialog.show();
    return true ; 
            }
```

here IDE shows that I have a error in startActivity(intent) line . 
I've tried that also : 
In MyItemizedOverlay class :

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
            return super.onTap(p, mapView); }
```

In MapsActivity class :

```
GeoPoint point2 = null ;
            confirmationOverlay.onTap(point2, mapView) ;
            int latt = point.getLatitudeE6() ;
            int longt = point.getLongitudeE6();
            final int endpointArray [] = {latt , longt};
            if(some condition to show the alert dialog after tapping)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
                dialog.setMessage("Confirm this location as end point ?");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,GetDestination.class);
                        intent.putExtra("geopoint" , endpointArray);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
```

For the if statement what sort of condition I can use ? If I set it just like lat>0 then the alertdialog appears without tapping on the map. 
I know this is very silly , but since I am new in both android & java , I hope you guys will consider it. Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your OnTap method in ItemizedOverlay class put:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.context).create();
           dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
           dialog.setMessage("Confirm this location as end point ?");

     dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.context, GetDestination.class);
                        //you must put your map activity    
                            MapsActivity.context.startActivity(intent);


                        }   
                    });


              dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I just checked your profile & found that all of the questions you asked or answered all are related with google maps . Seems like , you are working on a Map Application also . fahim.ahmed1988@gmail.com is my mailing address . If you wish you can contact with me . Having an map geek on contacts will be great for me . Thanks anyway . :-)

Comment: You welcome!:) And sure, why not. :) And you can contact me if you need some help with Maps and I'll contact you otherwise. :)